# Data type/value of argument checking

Tags: python

Consider ClassA that has a method that takes an argument, say a string.
This method then passes the argument to ClassB to do something with it.

Should ClassA be assuring that the argument is valid (string type, correct format, etc) or should ClassA not worry about it since ClassB is equipped to check this? Since ClassA is not doing anything with the argument except passing it to ClassB, an exception will be thrown regardless.

Example:

```
def ClassA:
    def method(self, arg1):
         '''
         Do I need:

         if type(arg1) is not str:
               raise TypeError()

         if ClassB has this?
         ''' 
         classb = ClassB(arg1)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about coding (so called defensive programming) than about quality assurance and testing. A better place would be http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

@Brenden In my experience, it is better to keep the validations as close to the end user or top of the stack as possible and have the underlying workers be as generic as possible.

In your case, you should probably even consider moving the validation from classB to classA so that your classB is free of the constraint and becomes a bit more generic to be called by other consumers with different needs.